# Keys in a dictionary from JSON

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, key

I'm importing a JSON dictionary. I need to know the name of the keys to work with it.

The dictionary is loading the data ok:

```
   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];    
  NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
  NSLog(@"tenga: %@",results);
```

but when I try to get the names of the keys the app crashes:

```
NSArray * keys = [results allKeys];
NSLog(@"keys: %@",keys); ...}
```

error message:

> [__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a16b30
>   2011-08-30 22:52:26.171 Twitter Search[1906:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a16b30'

Why is `allKeys` not working?

How do I get the names for my keys so I can start working with the objects?

edit

Im using the   http://code.google.com/p/json-framework [Stig Brautaset json framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework)

Comment: What sort of crash are you getting?

Comment: hi Tnx, I added the error in the question cheers

Comment: Also what JSON framework are you using?

Comment: Your server returns array, not a dictionary. Check value of response string, for example, print it using NSLog.

Comment: thank you, if I log the string, "responseString", i get a big string and if I log the dictionary I get a dictionary style log, so how to make sure the array goes to a dictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL that you obtained that JSON string from gave you an array, not an object i.e. it looked something like:

```
[ { "foo1" : "bar1" }, { "foo2" : "bar2" },... ]
```

Note the brackets `[ ]`.  In that situation, your JSON parser gave you an `NSArray` as the top level (Objective-C) object.  You need some logic like:

```
id results = [responseString JSONValue];
if ([results isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])
{
    // probably iterate through whtever is in it
}
else if ([results isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
{
    // dictionary at the top level.  Hooray!
}
else
{
    // something went horribly wrong, deal with it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is the results is not an NSDictionary but rather a NSArray. NSArray doesn't have the allKeys selector causing the crash. If you'd post more info on the JSON Framework you are using, we could help source the issue better

Answer (score 0):

Posted log says that this call `[responseString JSONValue]` returns `NSArray`.